# State of the art method for image captioning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

Image captioning problem: Given an image, describe what is happening in the image.

What is the state of the art work on image captioning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The state of the art works on image captioning problem can be found on 'Image Captioning Challege' with MSCOCO Dataset [here](https://competitions.codalab.org/competitions/3221#results).

Currently, 'Tencent', A Chinese giant is on the top with an approach based on Encoder-Decoder framework. It uses deep CNNs as encoders to encode the images into a vector that contains semantic information of the image  and LSTMs to decode them. They also use multi-stage attention mechanism during decoding and Reinforcement Learning to directly optimize the non-differential functions and scores like [CIDEr](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5726).

**Update Oct 2020:**
A lot have changed in the last 2.5 years, In addition to that, Now I'd recommend [this source (papers with code)](https://paperswithcode.com/task/image-captioning) or [this (madewithml)](https://madewithml.com/topics/image-captioning/) for literature review of SOTA papers as well as their github implementations.